# Why LogonUI.exe process username is blank and how to get correct username

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the username for LogonUI.exe process but I am getting blank. how can I get the correct username.

```
$logfile = 'C:\Users\Desktop\Process\log.txt'
if (!(Test-Path $logfile)) {
    New-Item $logfile -type file
}
do 
 {
 $owners = @{}
 gwmi win32_process |% {$owners[$_.handle] = $_.getowner().user}
 $data = get-process | select    processname,Id,PrivilegedProcessorTime,UserProcessorTime,@{l="Owner";e={$owners[$_.id.tostring()]}}
$allProcs = @(Get-WmiObject win32_process)

foreach($val in $allProcs) {    
$name = $val.ProcessName
"Before $name" | out-file -filepath $logfile -append
if ($name -eq 'LogonUI.exe') {
    $id = $val.Id
    $processtime = $val.PrivilegedProcessorTime.TotalMilliseconds
    $processtime1 = $val.UserProcessorTime.TotalMilliseconds
    $usename = $val.getowner().user
    "process value $name" | out-file -filepath $logfile -append
    "process value $id" | out-file -filepath $logfile -append
    #"process value $processtime" 
    #"process value $processtime1"
    "process value $usename" | out-file -filepath $logfile -append
    "Finished" | out-file -filepath $logfile -append
}
}
Start-Sleep -s 30
} while(1)
```

Here I am trying to get the username of LogonUI.exe process I am always getting it as blank.if I have more than one user logged into machine for for all the LogonUI user name is showing theblank. how can I get the correct user name for LogonUI process

Comment: The LogonUI process runs as system, you can't use that to determine what users are loggedon to your system.

Comment: Dear Lieven,   LoginUI.exe process runs when a user locked his account in system. if multiple users logged into system and locked, then multiple LogonUI.exe process are running in system. in task manager it is showing the username but by using PowerShell it is coming as blank.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of taskmanager showing the username next to LogonUI.exe? On every system I've checked, LogonUI is running as system.

Comment: Why are you trying to get the username for the LogonUI.exe process?

Comment: Dear Bill,  When multiple users logged into one system. I would like to know who account is locked and who is logged in currently.